# how to reduce the size of slideshow images in gallery

Tags: css, slideshow

please visit this link : http://gas1.newtrendzonline.com/

here slideshow images are too big in height.

please help me to reduce the size of image height.

I wanted both images should display in same height.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to resize these images in photoshop or use another image,
its out of porportion like this.